# Text Editor which shows \r\n?

Tags: text, text-editor, newline, carriage-return

I'm looking for a text editor that can show me the actual carriage returns and newlines.

E.g. if I save this string: `"This\rIs\r\nA\nString"`

Instead of showing

```
This
Is
A
String
```

I'm looking for some text editor which will show

```
This\rIs\r\nA\nString
```

I believe a problem with my text-file parsing in a certain program is being caused by inconsistent newline/carriage return/both on the ends of lines.

I could just make a program which can read a file and display it with that formatting, but I figured it'd be easier if anyone knew of one that can already do it.

Thanks!

[EDIT]
Forgot to specify I'm on Windows, and installing Cygwin isn't really an option.  Otherwise I would use vi or vim.
Also, if there's a way to do this in PSPad, which is already installed, it would be awesome if you knew that too.  Thanks!

Comment: Cygwin is not a prereq for Vim. gVim runs fine on native Windows.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

With [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm), you can show end-of-line characters. It shows CR and LF, instead of "\r" and "\n", but it gets the point across. However, it will still insert the line breaks. But you do get to see the line-ending characters.

To use Notepad++ for this, open the View menu, open the Show Symbols slide out, and select either "Show all characters" or "Show end-of-line characters".

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Here I've been using PSPad for years, preferring it over Notepad++, and now it fails me.  Not only that, but there's a forum post where people are pleading the author to add that feature, and he basically tells them to go away.  Maybe I'll consider switching to Notepad++...

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that it is under `View > Show Symbol`. Tip: Notepad++ is also great for finding characters and replacing them with line breaks, see details at http://superuser.com/q/34451/169199

Comment: I really like the command `od -c filename.csv`. This one is working on the Terminal app. http://dr-palaniraja.blogspot.ca/2011/06/how-to-view-windows-line-ending.html

Answer (score 10):

In **vi(m)**, check out:

```
:help 'list'
:help 'listchars'
```

Answer (score 10):

Sublime Text 3 has a plugin called RawLineEdit that will display line endings and allow the insertion of arbitrary line-ending type:

https://github.com/facelessuser/RawLineEdit

Comment: After installing the plugin, how do I activate it that is shows the line endings?

Comment: `shift + ctrl + p` is usually the way in Sublime to interact with plugins. Press these keys and start type the name of the plugin, you'll see the result.

Answer (score 4):

You can get this in Emacs by changing the mode. For example, here is what things look like in [Whitespace](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace) mode.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

On the Windows platform the [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) editor has an option to display white space (i.e. *View, White sapce* menu).

It also has an option to display the file in hex mode (i.e. *Tools, Hex Dump* menu).

Answer (score 2):

I'd bet that [Programmer's Notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org/) would give you something like that...

Answer (score 2):

Write a small program that does the trick. Depending on the language you use it takes between 10 seconds to 1 min. Faster than installing any application for sure. In command line with proper setup PHP

```
php -q

<?php $t=file_get_contents("filename"); echo str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), array("\\n", "\\r"), $t); ?>
```

Comment: I challenge you to write that program in *any* language in a second :-)

Comment: ok, a small typo, it should be 10

Comment: Don't vote me down, this is a valid solution, after all this is why PERL is created. Most importantly you can improve this method to search for any inconsistencies within a directory containing many files.

Comment: But I did say "I could just make a program which can read a file and display it with that formatting, but I figured it'd be easier if anyone knew of one that can already do it."  (but I didn't vote you down).

Answer (score 1):

Try [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm). It shows all characters. In addition, you could use the utility [dos2unix](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/cygutils.htm) to convert a file to all /n, or "conv" (same link) to convert either way.

Answer (score 1):

I am a huge fan of [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org).  It's very powerful, and cross-platform.  There's a plugin available for it called Whitespace which can do what you want.  If that's not enough, there's a hex viewing plugin and a hex editing plugin.

Comment: 8 years later... looks a bit outdated until some theme/font size changes (GTK+ FTW) but it still compiles fine. Java based editor, pretty cool! Somewhat impressed by this little project, handles large files faster than anything I've tried so far, very fast in general, and feature packed. Good one!

Answer (score 1):

[SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) does that very well with a single keystroke. It is also able to detect the most probably current line ending of the file (in case of mixed lines) and to convert them.
No need to install, lightweight, it can be used as a tool even if you don't want to give up your favorite editor.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to join the bandwagon so late but in Windows 10, Notepad2 will show them. Choose from the menu `View\Show Line Endings`

Answer (score 0):

**vi** can show all characters.

Answer (score 0):

[EmEditor](http://www.emeditor.com/)  does this.  You can also customize what symbols actually display to show them.

Answer (score 0):

GVIM runs on Windows, and there is VIM for cmd.

Check http://www.vim.org/download.php

Also, a quick look through the docs or google, or some vimmy friends can help you to use VIM's quick search and replace to fix the problem you are having I believe.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Mathematica, you can try with this command:

```
ReadList["filename.txt", Record, RecordSeparators -> {}] // InputForm
```

That will show all the /r and /n

Answer (score 0):

Slickedit and Notepad2 also show them. In Slickedit you can customize all sorts of invisible characters (whitespace, tabs, CRs, line feeds, ...) and display them with any character you wish.

Answer (score 0):

The best for replace \n \t and more: Programmer's File Editor
http://www.lancs.ac.uk/staff/steveb/cpaap/pfe/pfefiles.htm

Comment: The PSPad shows special characters: [PSPad.com](http://www.pspad.com)