# Text Editor which doesnt shows \r\n?

Tags: notepad++

Is there a feature in notepad++ that can place actual line breaks instead of in \r\n

- opposite from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446370/text-editor-which-shows-r-n) question and solution

Comment: If you can see the `\r` and `\n`, it's probably because they aren't actually line breaks but two separate characters (\ and r or n). You can just search and replace them with actual line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Find

```
\\r\\n
```

replace with

```
\r\n
```

"Extended (\n, \r, \t, \0, \x...)" box must be checked