# Get line separator of a txt with R

Tags: r

I have some txt and csv files.
I have to read the kind of line separator. I need to knoow if it's `\n` or `\r\n`
Is there a function that let me do that?
I tried with `scan` function with no result.

Comment: What do you need this info for? The `read*` functions for instance will work with either separator, no need to determine it beforehand.

Comment: I need to give this information to a my friend that has to import text/csv file with another software

Comment: So do you actually need to use R? [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) shows these if you enable `View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters`. (Also, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1446370/489704)).

Comment: I don't have notepad. And I'd like to do it cycling all files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use `file` via `system`:

For example:

```
system('file myfile.txt')
```

This will return a string something like:

```
myfile.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

You could automate iteration over files, and extract the relevant text from the results, with:

```
gsub('.*with | line terminators', '', 
     sapply(ff, function(f) system(paste('file', f), intern=TRUE)))
```

where `ff` is a vector of file names.

For example:

```
write.table(matrix(1:9, 3), f1 <- tempfile(fileext='.txt'))
write.table(matrix(1:9, 3), f2 <- tempfile(fileext='.txt'))
write.table(matrix(1:9, 3), f3 <- tempfile(fileext='.txt'))
ff <- c(f1, f2, f3)

gsub('.*with | line terminators', '', 
     sapply(ff, function(f) system(paste('file', f), intern=TRUE)))

##  C:\\Users\\John\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpUpmgXM\\file2ba07a471a01.txt 
                                                                 "CRLF" 
##  C:\\Users\\John\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpUpmgXM\\file2ba01ce5433.txt 
                                                                 "CRLF" 
##  C:\\Users\\John\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpUpmgXM\\file2ba0427a4b5e.txt 
                                                                 "CRLF"
```

Comment: Thank you. That's work very good. But sometimes `system('file myfile.txt')` gives me just myfile.txt: ASCII text

Comment: @dax90 - What's different about those files? (if you open them up and take a look)

Comment: The problem is that opening them they seems identical!  Both type are ";" separated. Maybe the difference is that `ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators` are in a windows format and `ASCII text` are in unix format. I don't know

Answer (score 0):

how many files do you have? maybe instead of finding out the seperators, read in the files and write them back into a file with a specified seperator.
Kind of a complicated way, but I could imagine that's easier than telling your friend always the seperator for each file.