# How to split Environment.NewLine?

Tags: c#

I want to count the number of lines in a text.

Below works fine:

```
int numLines = copyText.Split('\n').Length - 1;
```

However, I've been using `System.Environment.NewLine` in the whole of my code and when I try:

```
 int numLines = copyText.Split(System.Environment.NewLine).Length - 1;
```

It keeps bringing up a red wriggly line underneath stating cannot convert string to char. Been trying to rectify this but no luck. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To split on newline, you can use the following:

```
copyText.Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine },
               StringSplitOptions.None).Length - 1;
```

Here is a [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the overload which uses a string array.

Note that [System.Environment.NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is of type `System.String`. On Windows it is a 2 character string: `\r\n` and on Unix systems it is a 1 character string: `\n`. This is why you cannot use it as a char.

Wikipedia has a good article on newlines:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

I recommend reading it.

Comment: Only issue is though it fixed the red line, I can't perform a count as it returns 0 when there should be 5 lines: `int numberOfChar = copyText.Length - numLines;`

Comment: @user21255: You said `copyText.Split('\n').Length - 1;` works right? If it returns `0` when you use `System.Environment.NewLine`, that means the string does not contain `System.Environment.NewLine`. One solution is to just use your previous solution. Where is this string coming from?

Comment: It's coming from a rich text box where whatever text appears in the box, copyText is that text. The text is actually from a text file that goes into the rich text box.

Comment: @user21255: Probably the txt file is using unix newline convention. You could check with notepad++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446370/text-editor-which-shows-r-n

Answer (score 5):

As @Jesse Good noted, there are several kinds of newlines that might appear in a string.  A regular expression can be used to match the various kinds of newlines that might appear in a string:

```
var text = "line 1\rline 2\nline 3\r\nline 4";

/* A regular expression that matches Windows newlines (\r\n),
    Unix/Linux/OS X newlines (\n), and old-style MacOS newlines (\r).
    The regex is processed left-to-right, so the Windows newlines
    are matched first, then the Unix newlines and finally the
    MacOS newlines. */
var newLinesRegex = new Regex(@"\r\n|\n|\r", RegexOptions.Singleline);
var lines = newLinesRegex.Split(text);

Console.WriteLine("Found {0} lines.", lines.Length);

foreach (var line in lines)
  Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Output:

> Found 4 lines.
>   line 1
>   line 2
>   line 3
>   line 4

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a `String[]`:

```
int numLines = copyText.Split(new[]{System.Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None).Length - 1;
```

Comment: It solved the error but I'm having one little issue associated with this which I mentioned in a comment under the answer above.