# Python write line by line to a text file

Tags: python

I am trying to output the result from a Python script to a text file where each output should be saved to a line.

```
f1=open('./output.txt', 'a')
f1.write(content + "\n")
```

When I open `output.txt` with the regular `notepad` the results look like this:

```
color amber color aqua color analysis color app color adobe color alive app
```

However, when I open the file with `notepad++` it looks fine and each word is saved on a line.

How can make the script save the result line-by-line so it would show the same on the regular notepad?

Comment: see http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html you should use '\r\n' on Windows

Comment: What installation of python are you using?

Comment: Can you display the ending characters inside Notepad++ so that we can see what is happening? (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1446382/1559401) on how to enable that feature)

Comment: If the python documentation were written properly you would not need to ask this question. It's not your fault however, its the poor python documentation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, the problem you have is wrong line ending/encoding for notepad. Notepad uses Windows' line endings - `\r\n` and you use `\n`.

Answer (score 22):

You may want to look into os dependent line separators, e.g.:

```
import os

with open('./output.txt', 'a') as f1:
    f1.write(content + os.linesep)
```

Comment: I voted this down because of the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.linesep) on `os.linesep`

Comment: Good point, but then the OP shouldn't have an issue but they are,  suggesting to write `'\r\n'` is what I was responding to - using `os.linesep` is more portable.

Comment: The best solution! It's better than f1.write(content + "\n")

Comment: Do we absolutely need to `import os`?

Comment: @NdeSamuelMbah if you want to use `os.linesep` - you do.

Comment: Normally when using `f1.write(content + "\n")`, python automatically convert the `"\n"` to `os.linesep` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074811/what-is-os-linesep-for). The problem should elsewhere...