# python's subprocess.check_call says a nonempty file is empty

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I tried to print the number of line using 'wc -l' command using subprocess. It outputs that the file is empty while it is not.

```
import os
import subprocess
import tempfile
import time

filename = '/tmp/aaaaa'

with open(filename, 'w') as fout:
    fout.write('1')

with open(filename) as fin:
    print(fin.readlines())

subprocess.check_call('wc -l {}'.format(filename), shell=True)
```

Output:

```
['1']
0 /tmp/aaaaa
```

Why does it happen? My python version is 2.7.16.

Comment: According to man page "wc -l" counts the newlines and there isn't one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments,  you lack at least a newline.

`wc -l` counts the lines present in the file.

Assuming that is what you desire,  you need to create a line:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as fout:
    fout.write('1\n')
```

To make it independent of the OS do

```
import os

with open(filename, 'w') as fout:
    fout.write('1'+os.linesep)
```

See this [similar QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685518/python-write-line-by-line-to-a-text-file/35685564) for more info

If you don't need a line, check out [how to test if a file is empty in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964823/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-empty-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to spawn an external process in order to count the number of lines in a file. As you are noticing with `readlines`, if you use python's builtin handling of text files, the lines that are read in will also include any final line without a terminating newline character, so the problem encountered using `wc -l` does not arise. You can use a generator to convert this into a recipe that is suitable for counting the lines in a file without reading the whole file into memory at the same time.

```
with open("filename") as fin:
    num_lines = sum(1 for _ in fin)
```

If you are only interested in testing whether a file is empty, you could just read the first byte:

```
with open("filename", "rb") as fin:
    is_empty = not fin.read(1)
```

or you could use the file metadata:

```
is_empty = os.path.getsize(filename) == 0
```