# How to save Plain Text CSV Field to HTML In MySQL Database using PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, text-to-html

I'm reading data from CSV file for Fields which have value as Plain Text.

**Either need to convert CSV file Field Value to HTML or while Saving in DB.**

**Input:**

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam rhoncus
>   mauris ac tempus tempor. Maecenas porta, lorem in scelerisque aliquet,
>   ipsum lacus convallis orci, vitae tincidunt nunc sapien non tortor.
>   Ut sit amet erat vel tortor varius bibendum. Duis quis turpis laoreet,
>   hendrerit est a, consequat erat. Vivamus ultrices et dui a euismod.
>   Phasellus auctor neque quam, sed sagittis felis pretium eget. Praesent
>   a mollis felis, sed molestie ipsum.

**To Be Saved In Database:**

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam rhoncus mauris ac tempus tempor. Maecenas porta, lorem in scelerisque aliquet, ipsum lacus convallis orci, vitae tincidunt nunc sapien non tortor.</p> <p></p> <p> Ut sit amet erat vel tortor varius bibendum. Duis quis turpis laoreet, hendrerit est a, consequat erat. Vivamus ultrices et dui a euismod. Phasellus auctor neque quam, sed sagittis felis pretium eget. Praesent a mollis felis, sed molestie ipsum. </p>
```

Have used `nl2br`, `htmlentities` still not working.

Purpose it to save data in HTML form, So when i see on Admin TinyMCE Editor It look as needed.

Comment: neither of those functions will create paragraphs for you,

Comment: So what needs to be done? @nogad

Answer (score 0):

nl2br will simply convert "new line" character (\n) to its HTML equivalent

From you example, it seems that you are only interested in creating paragraphs. It that if the case, simply replace your "new line" character (\n, or maybe \n\r) by `</p><p>`

I would try the following :

```
$paragraphs = explode("\n", $text);
$htmlText = "<p>" . (join("</p><p>", $paragraphs)) . "</p>";
```

Comment: Nope. It's not working as needed. It's taking All things in to One `<p>ALL DATA</p>` tag

Comment: Then you need to figure out what to 'expode' your string on. In the code above I used \n character because it is the most common line break character. 

Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446370/text-editor-which-shows-r-n