# how to deal with line breaks and spaces in IE when using contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5, contenteditable

I have a  element inside my UI5 app. What I want to do is paste date into it then read it when you press a button. The problem is that it only works for Chrome and Firefox, but not for IE which is the one I need it for. When I read the data from the div IE does not properly read line breaks and tabs so I'm unable to correctly parse the data.

Here is my xml view code containing the div

```
<mvc:View
xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
height="100%"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
controllerName="sap.m.sample.Button.Page">

<Page
    class="sapUiContentPadding" >

    <content>
        <HBox>
            <Button type="Accept"
                    text="Accept"
                    press="onPress"
                    ariaDescribedBy="acceptButtonDescription genericButtonDescription">
            </Button>
        </HBox>
    </content>

    <FlexBox direction="Column" alignItems="Center">
        <html:div id="divinput" contenteditable="true" ><html:i>something</html:i> text</html:div>

    </FlexBox>
</Page>
```

This is my controller where I grab the data and parse it

```
sap.ui.define(['sap/m/MessageToast','sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller'],
function(MessageToast, Controller) {
"use strict";

var PageController = Controller.extend("sap.m.sample.Button.Page", {

    onPress: function (evt) {

        var divInput = this.getView().byId("divinput").getDomRef();
        //var inputA = this.getView().byId("input").getDomRef().innerHTML;
        var x = divInput.innerText;//innerHTML;

        var data = [];
        var rows = x.split("\n");

        for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
            var row = rows[i].split("\t");
            var obj = {NSN: row[0], QTY: row[1]};
            data.push(obj);
        }

        //now update the data with formatting
        this.updateData(data);    

    },

    updateData: function(data){

        var div = this.getView().byId("divinput").getDomRef();

        var text = "";

        for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
            if(data[i].NSN == "000123456"){
                text += "<b>" + data[i].NSN + "</b>    " + data[i].QTY +"<br>"; //there is no tab tag in html, use 4 spaces instead
            }
            else{
                text += data[i].NSN + "    " + data[i].QTY +"<br>";
               }
        }

        div.innerHTML = text;//"<i>something</i>, <b>something</b>";

    }
});

return PageController;

});
```

Comment: I think some browsers use `\rn` or `\r` instead of `\n`. Can you check for the presence of those?

Comment: Did not work for me. Not sure if it is due to the html div being inside the sapui5. I will look for other solutions.

Comment: There has to be a line ending character \ series of characters though. Just have to find the right one. Look at this for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446370/text-editor-which-shows-r-n