# Pandas read_csv is reading everything into one column for only one file python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, delimiter

I have multiple .dat files that I am trying to read into pandas with read_csv(). They are comma-delimited. All of the files are being read in properly, except for one, which is not separating on the commas and placing all the data into one column. I am so lost as to why this is happening, there is no difference between this file and the other ones, and I have tried so many different parameters.

Here is what I have:

```
col_names=['faketime',"rn","counter","DepthCm","BattVolts","latdeg","latmin",
"Longdeg","Longmin","fq","ns","HDOP","altB","DepthVolts","LatDDDDD",
"LongDDDDD","month","day","hour","minute","second","year"]
mo = pd.read_csv(i, names=col_names, skiprows=4, sep=',')
```

and here is a portion of the file

```
2015-05-08 07:17:56.7,7591,100001,0.11,12.46,81,37.6641,12,1.9694,1,11,0.7,-1.3,0.01,0.627735,0.03282334,5,8,7.000,17,56,20000
2015-05-08 07:17:59.54,7592,100002,0.06,12.45,81,37.6636,12,1.9702,1,11,0.7,-0.8,0.00,0.6277267,0.03283666,5,8,7.000,17,58,860000
2015-05-08 07:18:06.45,7593,100003,30.61,12.44,81,37.6633,12,1.9684,1,11,0.7,-0.6,2.008,0.6277217,0.03280667,5,8,7.000,18,5,770000
```

Comment: What is the value of `col_names`?

Comment: I have added it in an edit, sorry!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Works fine for me. If there is a problem in the file, it in not in those three lines. Consider splitting the file in halves and checking if the problem persists.

Comment: or maybe it's the EOL character? Open the file with a texteditor like Notepad++ to check. Then set it accordingly with the `lineterminator` parameter of [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: When I open it in a text editor there is " at the beginning and the end of every line, looks like in the other files there is only one at the beginning of every line. So should I set " as  the lineterminator?? Thank you this finally seems promising!

Comment: lineterminator or [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) is a special character. Texteditors often don't show it at all. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1446382/3104974) what to do to make it visible in Notepad++. Then check if it's the same for all your files. Tell me if that helps.

Comment: @ascripter the EOL's are CR LF for this file and the other ones, I still think it may have to do with the extra " at the end of every line in this file, but I'm not sure how to deal with that

Comment: If it's a lone double quote, it looks somehow like malformed quotation. Not knowing what the source of these files is: Is such a corrupt structure possible? Can you just remove the `"` and try then if it works?

Comment: Turns out the quotations in the other files were just around the timestamp at the beginning, and for some reason across the entire lines in this file. I ended up getting rid of all the quotations from this file and that solved the problem.