# Which newline character is in my CSV?

Tags: python, csv, ssis, delimiter, eol

We receive a `.tar.gz` file from a client every day and I am rewriting our import process using SSIS. One of the first steps in my process is to unzip the `.tar.gz` file which I achieve via a Python script.

After unzipping we are left with a number of CSV files which I then import into SQL Server. As an aside, I am loading using the CozyRoc DataFlow Task Plus.

Most of my CSV files load without issue but I have five files which fail. By reading the log I can see that the process is reading the Header and First line as though there is no HeaderRow Delimiter (i.e. it is trying to import the column header as `ColumnHeader1ColumnValue1`

I took one of these CSVs, copied the top 5 rows into Excel, used Text-To-Columns to delimit the data then saved that as a new CSV file.
**This version imported successfully**.

That makes me think that somehow the original CSV isn't using `{CR}{LF}` as the row delimiter but I don't know how to check. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your favorite binary file viewer is your friend in this case.  I don't know python or would suggest a powershell script to dump a bit of your file as hex.

Comment: You can use HxD hex editor to check. `CR`=`0x0D` and `LF`=`0x0A`

Comment: Not a programmatical way, but if there are text editors which can show the end-of-line (eol) chars. There is Notepad++ and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446370/text-editor-which-shows-r-n).

Comment: Using VS Code can show you where the new line characters occur as well. Any text editor really can probably confirm it for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the suggestion commented by @[vahdet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4636715/vahdet) because I already had notepad++ installed. I can't find the same option in EmEditor but it may exist

For those who are curious, the files are using `{LF}` which is consistent with the other files. My investigation continues...

Comment: Are you sure? CR + LF isn't the same as LF only.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you have EmEditor, you can use EmEditor to find the eol character in two ways:

1. Use View > Character Code Value... at the end of a line to display a dialog box showing information about the character at the current position.
2. Go to View > Marks and turn on Newline Characters and CR and LF with Different Marks to show the eol while editing. LF is displayed with a down arrow while CRLF is a right angle.

Some other things you could try checking for are: file encoding, wrong type of data for a field and an inconsistent number of columns.