# String.equals() method not matching in Windows

Tags: java, windows, macos, java.util.scanner, equals

I made a Java program using Eclipse on macOS and it ran fine. When I switched it to Eclipse on Windows I started getting an error.

The failing condition was an if statement that was working fine on mac. On Windows I tried debugging the problem. `scanner.next()` was giving the correct output if I printed it out. If I compared it however it did not work. I also tried copying and pasting the output into my condition and it still did not work. I tried including if there was a \n that I could not see and this also did not work. The below is the code for it.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("text from file with line 1 being 'TRAILING PERFORMANCE'");
toggleDelimiter(scanner); // helper method that switches the scanner to read by lines or tokens

if(!scanner.next().equals("TRAILING PERFORMANCE")) {
// Throw error here if the first line is not TRAILING PERFORMANCE
}
```

The condition should return false and no error thrown for the file I am using as I know it works. As stated before the exact same code runs fine on Eclipse with macOS.

EDIT:
I have now also tried appending \n, \n\r, and System.lineSeparator() to the end of "TRAILING PERFORMACE" and it still does not work.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: To debug this, you should extract `scanner.next()` into a String variable, and then iterate through the String to see what characters exist in each position.

Comment: This is probably an issue with the file you are reading from being created on mac OS, and thus having different line endings than windows.

Comment: @Nexevis the error was thrown by my code so it doesnt matter. It should not go into the body of the if statement at all.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that helped get me somewhere. It looks like there is an extra line break at the end but "TRAILING PERFORMACE\n" still dosent work either.

Comment: @plum0 The file is a PDF that I read into my Java program and then go through it. I printed it out to a text file once and it is formatted the same

Comment: How does toggleDelimiter() do the toggling? From the quick look it does not have reference to scanner (unless the above code to it is global?)

Comment: You need to continue to see what your Scanner is returning to you. And no, never tag an extra line-feed on the end of the String, but instead `.trim()` the String returned by the Scanner **if needed** (but I don't see that being the case here). Regardless, without more data and [mre] code, we're relegated to guessing at the problem and its solution. To my eye, your question will remain unanswerable unless you greatly improve it.

Comment: So just to clarify, this was an issue with line endings not being the same then?

Comment: @plum0 Seems so. I am still unsure of what Windows was having it put instead of \n but after including the extra method call it seems to work.

Comment: @ZVets
In case you were curious, Mac is a unix-based OS. Windows uses carriage returns as well as line feeds, whereas unix uses just line feeds. You can find a little bit more information on that [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html) as well as [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-great-newline-schism/). You can visually see the line endings in a text editor like notepad++ by [enabling the functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446370/text-editor-which-shows-r-n) to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After learning that Windows will change the new line characters without me doing anything, I was able to find the method setLineSeparator() in PDFBox (which I was using to read the PDF) and set the new line character to "\n" so it was able to work as it did before.