# I am trying to replace a text of a file with certificate using sed command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

cat file.txt

This is my CRT.

I am taking the certificate input from user using read command.

Below is my input.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
\r\nGGHIDqjCCApICCQDbD5hdEvLLsTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBkTELPOAkGA1UEBhMC\r\nU0ExGTAXBgNVBAgMEEVhc3Rlcm4gUHJvdmluY2UxEjAQBgXBhnhfdxd/liuffgfgseeadR4DmKACPesFIiiiqEKi9ouJtDY7mg7I7\r\n8vPudZ2Qs6x9F/i6/1WBz1UoZBT//gHYYRIBsOUCGwxZJCs1Lcy2zMWf1Um\r\n-
----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

How can I replace this CRT with this input certificate.
I tried `sed "s/CRT/$INPUT/" file_name` but that is not working.

Comment: `replaceEscaped=$(sed 's/[&/\]/\\&/g' <<< "$INPUT"); sed "s/CRT/$replaceEscaped/" file_name`. See [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed)

Comment: @Wiktor, I think you should add this an an answer as I think it does what Rahul is looking for by maintaining the text `\r\n` in the output.

Comment: I do not have to, this answer already [exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```sh
sed "s:CRT:$INPUT:" file_name
```

Your issue is likely to be the slashes `/` in `$INPUT`. `sed` can use multiple characters for the delimiter, so here I've used `:`, which isn't in `$INPUT`, bypassing the problem.

This works for me:

```sh
INPUT='hello/world\r\n'
echo CRT example | sed "s:CRT:$INPUT:"
```

The output is:

```
hello/world
 example
```

'example' is on a new line because of the `\r\n` at the end of `$INPUT`. If `INPUT='hello/world'`, without the `\r\n`, then the output is all one line:

```
hello/world example
```

See also: [Replace a string including a slash “/” using sed command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382077/replace-a-string-including-a-slash-using-sed-command/382079)

Comment: My input was -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\nMIIDqjCCApICCQDbD5hdEvLLsTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBkTELMAkGA1UEBhMC\r\nU0jui/jgdffjTYUFmluY2UxEjAQBgNVBAcMCUFsIEtob2Jh\r\ncjEvMC0GUm\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE----- but i am not seeing \r\n in my output when I used sed "s:CRT:$INPUT:"

Comment: Are you seeing a new line after '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----' or is everything on the same line? `\r\n` is the Window's new line character, so a text editor will simply show that as a new line.

Comment: @Rahul, I've added an example of what I mean about seeing a new line to the answer.

Comment: I want the exact value of Input i.e including \r\n as text.

Comment: It's down to each programme you use how the `\r\n` is interpreted; it's nothing to do with sed. Those characters *are* there, it's just the programming displaying your text file is *choosing* not to show them and putting in a new line instead. If you copy and paste, those characters will get copied as well. See: [Text Editor which shows \r\n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446370/text-editor-which-shows-r-n). Exercise: In your terminal, try typing `echo $INPUT` and see what comes out; I don't think your terminal will show your the `\r\n` either.

Comment: See [Control Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) on Wikipedia.